# Instantiate a prefab pointing in the direction of another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

## The Issue

I'm making a 2D Unity game where the main weapon of your character is a fireball gun. The idea is that a fireball will shoot out of the player's hand at the same angle the player's hand is pointing. I have 3 issues:

1. When I shoot the fireball, since the fireball is a RididBody, it pushes the player. This is because I've made the centre of the player's arm (the same place where the fireball shoots from) the point at which the arm rotates around the player (what is meant to be the shoulder);
2. To instantiate the fireball prefab on the arm, the only way I know how to do it is by using a piece of code which requires the arm to be a RigidBody. This means that the arm is affected by gravity and falls off the player on start unless I freeze the arm's y-axis movement, which means that when the player jumps, while the arm does not fall, it floats at the same y-position as where it started while moving along the x-axis; and
3. When the fireball is shot, the angle from which it is propelled after being shot is not the same angle as the angle of the player's arm.

### Instantiating the Fireball

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        pew.Play();
        var fireballTransform = Instantiate(fireballPrefab);    //creates a new shot sprite
        fireballTransform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + horizMultiplier, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        fireballTransform.rotation = orientation;
        fireballTransform.transform.Rotate(0, 0, transform.rotation.z);
    }

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))    // moves right
    {
        orientation = 0;
        horizMultiplier = 0.08F;
    }

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))    // moves left
    {
        orientation = 180;
        horizMultiplier = -0.08F;
    }
```

This piece of code is located within the script applied to the player's arm. The movement of the arm works fine and the problem seems to be either within this piece of code or the code for my fireball (which I will put next). A few definitions:

- **pew** is a sound effect played when the fireball is shot;
- **horizMultiplier** is the distance from the arm's centre which I would like the fireball to instantiate (also dependant of if the player) is facing left or right); and
- **orientation** is which direction the player is facing (left or right). The fireball is then instantiated facing that same direction.

### Fireball Script

```
public Vector2 speed = new Vector2();   // x and y forces respectively

private Rigidbody2D rb;                 // shorthand
private float rotation;

void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();           // shorthand
        rotation = rb.rotation;

        if (rotation == 0)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.right * speed.x);   // propels right
        }

        if (rotation == 180)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.left * speed.x);    // propels left
        }
    }
```

I believe this code is explanatory enough with comments (if not please comment and I'll address any question). I believe an issue could also be in this piece of code because of the lines: `rb.AddForce(Vector3.right * speed.x);` and `rb.AddForce(Vector3.left * speed.x);` as these add directional forces to the object. I don't know is this is objective direction (right or left no matter what direction the object the force is being applied to is facing) or if it's right or left in terms of the object-- say if an object was rotated 90 degrees clockwise and that object had a force applied so that it moves right making the object move downwards.

What I'm expecting to happen is the player's arm will turn so that when a fireball is fired it is fired in the direction the arm is facing. The arms turning mechanics are fine, it's just trying to properly instantiate the fireball. Can anyone help with any of the issues I've laid out?

Answer (score 0):

How I would go about this:

1. Add an empty transform as child of the arm and move it to where the fireball should spawn. Also make sure the rotation of it is such that its forward vector (the local z-axis) points to where the fireball should go. To see this, you need to set "Local" left of the play button.
2. Spawn the fireball at the transform's position with its rotation.
3. Ignore collision between the arm's/player's collider and the fireball's collider with https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreCollision.html. If necessary, you can enable the collision between the two colliders again after 1s or so.
4. Set the fireball rigidbody's velocity to speed * rigidbody.forward.

If you need help with the code, please post it so I can see what's going on.

Edit:

1. The arm definitely doesn't require a Rigidbody.
2. You can just use Instantiate(prefab, position, rotation) as shorthand.
3. Is this for a 2D game?

Also, I'm going to sleep now but I'll gladly try to help tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

### Your Issues

1) You should be masking the fireball's layer not to collide with your player's layer.
You can find more info about this here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html
(note: make sure you're on the Physics2D panel, and not the Physics one, as that's for 3D)

2) There is a setting called `gravityScale` in `RigidBody2D`. You should set this to 0 if you don't want gravity to be affecting your object. More info: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody2D.html

### Fireball Instantiate

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        pew.Play();

        var position = hand.transform.position + hand.transform.forward * horizMultiplier;
        var rotation = hand.transform.rotation;

        var fireball = Instantiate<Fireball>(fireballPrefab, position, rotation);   
        fireball.StartMoving();
    }
```

### Fireball Script

```
private Rigidbody2D rb;                 // shorthand
private float rotation;

public float Speed;

public void StartMoving()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();           // shorthand
        rb.velocity = transform.forward * Speed;
    }

void OnTriggerEnter(....) { .... }
```